# PostgreSQL update certain row

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I want to update verified from 'f' to 't' for certain rows, but it will update all the rows when I do this:

```
UPDATE
  news
SET
  verified = 't'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
        verified
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum
    FROM
        news
  ) AS foo
WHERE
 rownum = 1 or rownum = 15 or rownum = 32 or rownum = 54;
```

Can someone tell me where the problem is? Thanks

Comment: you are not joining the derived table to the target table. You need something like `and news.id = foo.id`

Answer (score 0):

From the PostgreSQL documentation for the UPDATE clause:

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table.

So, your query creates the cross product of the news table with the results of the SELECT clause, which of course is also the news table (which I will call "foo" because of your AS clause).  Every single row from the news table is accompanied by every single row from the foo result table, creating nxn rows where n is the number of rows in news.  So, for every news row, there is at least one foo row that is selected by the WHERE clause.  Thus, every row of the news table is modified.

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  (Can the OVER parameter be blank?  And why select verified in the foo query?)  But you may want to join each foo row to the proper news row in the WHERE clause, perhaps by primary key.

Comment: I'm new to postgresql, I'm not sure what do you mean by: Or the WITH clause may be helpful. Could you show me an example?

Comment: Now that I think about it, not sure the WITH clause would add value.  Editing to remove that part of my answer.

Comment: Ok no worries, I used title instead of rownum to update my tables and it works fine. Thanks for the explanation anyway